# How did the term 'Buttered the bread' originate?

Tags: landing, aviation-history

I've heard this term used a few times to describe an exceptionally smooth landing

Comment: "Exceptionally smooth" landings are not necessarily good ones. I've heard these "gentle" touchdowns referred to as "like a butterfly with sore feet", but firm touchdowns are necessary depending on conditions.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/6270/62)

Answer (score 2):

Back when actual butter was the main spread to put on bread, it took a very gentle touch to spread butter straight from the refrigerator (icebox) without tearing up the bread.  Thus, a very smooth landing might be said to have "buttered the bread" because it went on smoothly enough to keep from tearing anything up.

This probably also evolved into "greased it on" or "greaser" to refer to a similarly smooth landing.

Comment: Oh how I remember this... while I did not like toasted bread it was much easier to spread cold butter on warm toast.

Comment: What is the main spread to put on bread now? In my experience, your first sentence (except the icebox part of course) is still true.